# Include in twig template

Tags: wordpress, templates, include, twig

I use Gantry5 template on WordPress CMS.

In my particle twig file **exampleparticle.html.twig**:

```
{% if particle.style == 'style2' %}
    Some title here
    {% include 'style2.html.twig' %}
```

On page i see text "**Some title here**" and under this text error:

```
Error while rendering exampleparticle particle.
```

If use this string:

```
{% include 'style2.html.twig' ignore missing %}
```

Then i see only text: "**Some title here**". It turns out that the system can not find the file style2.html.twig. Both files located in one directory.

P.S. Sorry for my english.

Comment: What's inside `style2`, you tried including an empty file

Comment: included file not empty

Comment: No i meant try with an include that is empty :-) You probably have an error the `style2` template. The questionmark dissapeared from my question

Comment: included file It must also have a  twig markup ?

Comment: Not required. Update question with what is inside the 2nd template?

Comment: For example, in style2.html.twig i just write plain text like "hello World".if this construction will work, then I can write the necessary code.

Comment: I try work with empty file and not empty file, with full path to file, but this did not give the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

your if statement. it should be closed with `{% endif %}`

and most likely when you try to include that file twig expects some route or the file is just empty. a problem i had once looking like this was that there were 2 files in directory "partial" and file one included file two.

but `{% include 'file2' %}` did not work it had to be `{% include 'partial/file2' %}`.

so adding routing to the include and exeting the IF statement may fix your problem

Comment: if statement, of course, is closed. Its just part of code. All worked except include function